# Moving navigator in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to fetch data for example from this website: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading

To get the data with high resolution, I have to set the min max to small value and then I have to go over the complete diagram.

It is possible to get data from the website with "Highcharts.charts[0].series[0]"

But I didn't find a possibility to programable changing the navigators, to get other data ranges.

Is it possible to move the navigator to a specific position?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You can mouse drag the navigator to change the extremes dynamically.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to get data by a script for a specific time frame, so I would like to change the extremes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Axis.setExtremes` function for this.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/am3cgo5w/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: Thank you for your answear. Here is my code if somebody needs:

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answear. Here is my code if somebody needs:

I saw, that the redraw event will be called 5 times till the diagram is finishd redrawn

```
counter = 1
// Get chart
chart = $('#highcharts-graph').highcharts()
// add event
Highcharts.addEvent(chart, 'redraw', function (e) {
console.log(counter); 
counter = counter+1; 
if(counter>5){
    console.log('finish loaded')
    function2()
}
})
var newSelectedMin = 0
var newSelectedMax = 10
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(newSelectedMin, newSelectedMax);
```